# How to change a users name on a Shared Photostream?

Tags: apple-id, photo-stream, icloud

Shared Photostreams are a fantastic way to keep in touch with family and relatives. Comments on Shared Photostreams make them even better as this allows discussion about the action in the picture. However, here is the problem lies: there are two subscribers who share the exact same name (one married into the family, attaining the same last name as well) - for clarity, let's say "Jessica Smith".

So, when "Jessica Smith" comments, it is impossible to tell which person this is actually referring to. In normal life we have gotten accustomed to including the one's middle name when referring to her. So, the goal is to change it so that one is "Jessica Smith" and the other is "Jessica *Grace* Smith".

**How is this possible?**

"Jessica Grace Smith" has tried to change her Apple ID name by managing her Apple ID online, but this has had limited success by updating some Photostreams and not others. Also, I have tried removing her, making sure her email was in my contact for her as "Jessica *Grace* Smith" and then re-inviting her, but this didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way that it is possible to do this - as of iOS 6 - is to start a new Shared Photostream after the Apple ID name has been changed. So for this case:

1. "Jessica Smith" changes her name to "Jessica Grace Smith" using [appleid.apple.com](http://appleid.apple.com).
2. I (or the Shared Photostream originator) creates a new Shared Photostream, and invites everyone to it, including "Jessica Grace Smith".
3. The new name (with the middle name) will now correctly show on the new Shared Photostream.

This doesn't have any real negative effects because all the subscribers can stay subscribed to the old Photostream if they desire (and the originator leaves it that way). The other plus, is that one can un-subscribe from the old Photostream to save space.

Answer (score 1):

Following these steps should do the trick:

1. **Unsubscribe** to the shared photo album.
2. Change the full name on the **Apple ID** account.
3. **Subscribe** again to the Photo Stream by getting a new invitation.

Afterwards, all the comments you'll post should display the *new* name. The thing is that once a comment is posted, the name does not change, so if you want to *change* the name on an already posted comment, you'll have to **Delete** the comment, follow the steps, and post it again.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, this didn't work. I unsubscribed her, then she changed her name at appleid.apple.com. I then re-invited her and the comments showed the same way that they did. What is interesting is that her name under my Photostream subscribers is correct. It is just the (new) comments and "likes" still show the "incorrect" name.